# Changing cell border without affecting the surrounding cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel, how to define border of one cell without changing border settings of surrounding cells?

Comment: The borders are between the cells rather than "inside" a cell.  So changing a border affects all cells touching the border.

Comment: Would you like to re-word your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borders applied to cells also apply to their adjacent cell(s). Per Microsoft [KB on Borders](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Apply-or-remove-cell-borders-on-a-worksheet-dc8a310b-92e3-46a7-9f17-2ab745810f4a) (2007)-

> NOTE
>
> - If you apply a border to a selected cell, the border is also applied
>     to adjacent cells that share a bordered cell boundary. For example, if
>     you apply a box border to enclose the range B1:C5, the cells D1:D5
>     acquire a left border.
> - If you apply two different types of borders to a shared cell boundary,
>     the most recently applied border is displayed.